# How to retrieve values from variable in flutter?

Tags: flutter, model, response

I am following a tutorial for accessing payments in flutter using brain tree.

this is the method described in tutorial.

```
payNow() async {
    BraintreePayment braintreePayment = new BraintreePayment();
    var data = await braintreePayment.showDropIn(
        nonce: clientNonce, amount: amount, enableGooglePay: true, nameRequired:true);

    print("Response of the payment $data");


  }
```

on printing the var data i receive this.

```
{message: Payment Nouce is ready., status: success, paymentNonce: tokencc_xxxxxxxxxxxxx}
```

and from this i want to retrieve paymentNonce value i.e "tokencc_xxxxxxxxxxxxx"

better would be if i could get values in a model class.

Comment: use this data['paymentNonce'] to get value of paymentNonce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use data["paymentNonce"] to get what you want, since it's JSON (Key value pair)